# Android spinner inside a custom control - OnItemSelectedListener does not trigger

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am writing a custom control that extends LinearLayout. Inside that control I am using a spinner to let the user select an item from a list.
The problem I have is that the OnItemSelectedListener event does not fire. When moving the same code to an Activity/Fragment all is working just fine.

I have followed some answers that was given to others asking about the same issue, and nothing helped. still the event does not fire.

This is my code after I followed the answers that suggested to put the spinner inside my layout XML instead of by code. I am getting the same result when I try to just "new Spinner(ctx)"...

layout XML:

```
  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/accSpinner"        
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="0dip" />
```

Initialization function of the control (called on the control constructor):

```
private void init()
{
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    mAccountBoxView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.control_accountselector, null);

    mTxtAccount = (TextView)mAccountBoxView.findViewById(R.id.txtAccount);
    mSpinner = (Spinner)mAccountBoxView.findViewById(R.id.accSpinner);

    mAccountBoxView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                mSpinner.performClick();
            }
        });

    setSpinner();
    addView(mAccountBoxView);
}

private void setSpinner()
{       
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mItems);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);             
    mSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                String selectedItem = mItems.get(position);
                handleSelectedItem(selectedItem);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {

            }
        });     
}
```

The spinner raises just fine when i touch my control and the list of items is there as it should.
When I click an item the spinner closes but I am never getting to onItemSelected nor onNothingSelected..

Any ideas?

Comment: The code looks fine... How did test that `onItemSelected()` isn't called?

Comment: break point, toast, log... even tried all of them together once :\

Comment: I am using eclipse.. Also tried to clean and rebuild the project several times..

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer!

I have initialized the spinner adapter with an empty arraylist of items. Then the actual items were added using this public function:

```
public void addItem(String item)
{
    mItems.add(item);       
}
```

I have changed the function to this:

```
public void addItem(String item)
{
    mItems.add(item);
    mDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now the adapter knows about the new items and the event is fired.

When I have moved the code to an activity there was nothing to call it from the outside so the items were in the array before I set the adapter and this is why it worked there.

Comment: (Upvote for solving it yourself.) You should be able to combine those two lines into `mDataAdapter.add(item)`, it calls `notifyDataSetChanged()` for you.

Comment: I am using the item list in some other places and prefer to work with an external reference for readability and convenient. Thank you for the suggestion.